# How to safely pass parameters in the url

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, urlencode, url-encoding

I am using urls like this parameters

```
http://localhost/articles/?author=Ben%20Cooper%2CAlex%20Hunter&title=.....&tags=..
```

I urlencode them in the links. This all works until there are special characters in the parameters.

For example

```
http://localhost/articles/?author=..&title=&tags=..
```

If, in title I have Love & Life, first time it encodes it has Love+%26+Life, sometimes it becomes `Love+%26amp%3B+Life.`

Why is this happening?  I appreciate any help.

Comment: in the latter case it is being XML/HTML encoded before it is being URL encoded (although the `(space)` to `+` transformation is outside the definition of percent encoding): It  goes `Love & Life` -> `Love &amp; Life` -> that stuff. But since I don't use either PHP or Cake ... can't say more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) first. That will turn `&amp;` (which is encoded for html, not urls) into `&` *then* `unlencode()` which will turn it into `%26`

HTML and URLs have different reserved chars and are encoded differently. A lot of frameworks will automatically encode html entities to help prevent your page from rendering oddly. Imagine you had `<` in a string, that could screw up the page when it was displayed so it will get echo'd to the html as `&lt;` and the browser will render it as `<`instead of treating it as part of a tag.

You can't directly encode `&lt;` into `%3C` (`<` urlencoded) because it will think you literally want to encode `&lt;` and not `<` this is why you need to make a pass through `html_entity_decode()`

Here is a code snippet:

```
$str = 'Love &amp; Life'; //start with string that may or may not contain htmlentities
$decodedStr = html_entity_decode($str); //replace html entities with their literal counterparts
$urlEncodedStr = urlencode($decodedStr); //urlencode!
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As to where exactly the html entities are encoded or why it's encoding sometimes but not others, I can't help without actually looking at your code.